# Unable to create postgres server (pgAdmin)

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, pgadmin

I am trying to create a postgres server on my local. But I am getting this error:
[image: Snapshot]

This is my first time using postgresql so kindly let me know what I am doing wrong here.

I watched some tutorials and tried following the steps in them. Please refer to the snapshot for details of the error.

Comment: Your question misses a little bit of context. What did you do? Here we just see that the client is not able to connect to a local server. What did you install exactly/version? Which tutorial did you follow?

Comment: As pointed out by @c3R1cGFy , I missed out installing the server and directly jumped to the pgAdmin. Silly of me!! Thanks for the help guys. I would provide way more clarity in future questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The screenshot you provided is actually the postgres client (pgadmin).
You need to have the server installed and started on port 5432. Only then you will be able to connect the client on localhost:5432

Here is the installation/download link: https://www.postgresql.org/download/

Also, you can use docker to start such a database and then connect to it. https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres  The command would be i.e.

```
docker run --name postgres -p 5432:5432 -d postgres
```

Keep in mind that all data will disappear with docker once you delete the container. However, you can use volumes to persist them and reuse during your development.